# jQuery.countdown pass seconds instead of time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

We are trying to use jQuery.countdown and since it's dependant on the local time, we wanted to pass seconds to it. We are using multiple instances. How would we pass seconds until the end instead of date?

```
<div data-countdown="2016/01/01 01:32:12"></div>
<div data-countdown="2017/01/01 04:12:25"></div>
<div data-countdown="2018/01/01 01:12:22"></div>
<div data-countdown="2019/01/01 00:22:21"></div>
```

```js
$('[data-countdown]').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this), finalDate = $(this).data('countdown');
    $this.countdown(finalDate, function(event) {
        $this.html(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
    });
});
```

If someone can make a custom function, instead of jquery.countdown - we could use that too.

Comment: Create a new date with seconds added to it and pass it.

Answer (score 0):

Use format Option as 'S' in countdown

```
$this.countdown({
   until: someTime,
   format: 'S' )}
```

[documentation](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html)